# How to get last modified record from Elasticsearch, when there is no timestamp field?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-py

In my index, I don't have a timestamp field. I need to fetch only new records added every day, instead of fetching all records every time. Is there any way to do this even though I don't have any timestamp field

Comment: Are you using a linearly increasing numeric ID for your documents?

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch doesnot store such fields.

You can use ingest feature or obviously add a timestamp field.